# Passing geometry type from Database to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, geometry

Selecting from database field that has Geometry type returns weird string to PHP.

Is there in PHP some kind of class that can convert that string to something usable? Or I have to convert all my sql queries (ex using `AsText(geo_field)`) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [brick/geo](https://github.com/brick/geo) for this purpose. It can read all geometries (`Point`, `LineString`, `Polygon`, etc.) as typed objects  that you can interact with:

You can select using `ST_AsText()` from your database, then:

```php
$polygon = Polygon::fromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 0 3, 3 3, 0 0))');
echo $polygon->area(); // 4.5
```

If you're using Doctrine, the library comes with mapping types that do the job for you.

Disclaimer: I'm the author.